# Laravel middleware does not recognize user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I want to apply a Middleware that check if user has `is_staff` or `is_superuser` set to **1**, then he can access to admin dashboard otherwise he can not access it.

So in order to do this, I created this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            if(auth()->user()->isSuperUser() || $request->user()->isStaffUser()) {
                return $next($request);
            }else{
                return redirect('/home');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is it returns `redirect('/');`  meaning that the middleware does not recognize that user is already logged in, however he is signed in.

I have registered the Middleware like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticated::class,
```

And apply it to my admin routes (`RouteServiceProvider.php`):

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            ...

            Route::middleware('auth.admin')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
        });
    }
```

And here is `admin.php` routes:

```
Route::get('/',function (){
    return view('admin.master');
});
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you try checking the `Auth::check()` if returning something?

Comment: @VLDCNDN It returns *null*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you also need to add the `web` middleware to the admin routes.

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
            ...
        Route::middleware(['web', 'auth.admin'])
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->prefix('admin')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
    });
}
```

`Auth::check()` tries to get the currently logged in user from the session.

`web` middleware group activates session, it has a bunch of middleware applied

```php
//app/Http/Kernel.php
 'web' => [
     \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,            
     \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
     \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
     \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
     \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
     \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
 ],
```

Without `web` middleware session won't be available

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the whole routing but I bet your use never gets logged.

You probably apply:

```
 Route::middleware('auth.admin')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
```

for all admin routes. So you have login form and when you fill in data to login, users hits some endpoint which also applies this middleware, so it never goes to controller where you actually log in user because middleware redirects back to /.

You should apply the middleware to all routes except of login/remind password otherwise it's impossible to log in.